# Differential Equation RLC circuit analysis.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[RLC circuit analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NE9J.jpg)

I am stuck solving this problem.  I've attached the question and my solution. My particular solution seems to cancel!

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your "guess" fits the general form of a homogeneous solution.  Since it's a solution to the homogeneous problem, plugging it in on the left side gives you zero.

The solution to this problem is to modify your particular solution.  Use
$$
i_p(t) = Ate^{-10t}
$$

Comment: Thank you! So how do I know to make my solution $Ate^{-10t}$ rather than just $Ae^{-10t}$?  Where does the $t$ come from?

Comment: Oh never mind I see what you are saying!  The complimentary homogenous equation has the solution$y_c = C_1e^{-10t} + C_2e^{-20t}$ which has the similar term $\mathbf {C_1e^{-10t}}$.  New question, sorry!  If the particular solution had been let's say $\mathbf{C_1e^{-9t}}$ would I still need to modify my guess with an added $t$?  Basically under what conditions do I need to modify my guess with a $t$ multiple?

Comment: The answer to that one is no.  You need to modify your guess if (but only if) one in the terms of your guess matches one of the terms of the homogeneous solution.

Comment: Perfect, thank you again!